# Transaction logs created when a stored procedure run in Visual Studio takes 3 times the space, when same SP is run in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, logging, ssms

As we knows that there are transaction logs created in Sql Server, I have a stored procedure, 
when it is run from Visual Studio, the transaction logs created are 3 times in size (around 150 GB) as compared to, when the same SP is run in Sql Server Management Studio(around 50 GB), i donot need these transaction logs. 
My Questions are : 
why is there a difference in size of 3 times.?
Is there a setting available, so that these logs not get created.. as i don't need these logs
Is there a trick, so that i can do something that logs created more than a particular size, are over-written by next logs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this isn't a production server, and that you'll never need to restore to a specific point in time...

[You can set your database's recovery mode to `simple`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx)

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```

From MSDN:

> Automatically reclaims log space to keep space requirements small,
>   essentially eliminating the need to manage the transaction log space.

As far as the discrepancy in log growth between Visual Studio and Management Studio... my guess is that Visual Studio might be running the stored procedure multiple times, possibly to gather metadata.  I would profile the database in question and see what is actually hitting it in each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example for your Query?
Even 50 GB seems excessive for a store procedure.

BTW - You need the logs because the database is updated based on the information contained in them.

You should be able to alter the stored procedure so that you either write less information to the logs or have the database write the information in the logs to the database at regular intervals with the Checkpoint command.

I recently had an issue where a series of poorly formed statement that were filling up the logs, rewriting the query helped me reduce the log size (and the sp ran faster)